# Can I pass method as an argument in unittest assertIn?

Tags: python, python-unittest

I am new to unittest and I want know if there any way I can pass methods inside unittest assertIn function as an argument. I want to see if an API call return JSON object with the word "code" in it. If "code" is not in the object I want it to assert.

I get the following error

> TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

as unittest function sees method as NoneType value.

```
import unittest
class Testing(unittest.TestCase):

def test_createDepositAddress(self):
        result = client.createDepositAddress({"currencySymbol":"BTC"})
        self.assertIn("code", result)
```

How can I check if "code" in inside the JSON object that is returned from calling client.createDepositAddress({"currencySymbol":"BTC"})

Here is the JSON payload returned from calling client.createDepositAddress({"currencySymbol":"BTC"})

```
{
    "code": "CRYPTO_ADDRESS_ALREADY_EXISTS"
}
```

Comment: `client.createDepositAddress` is returning `None`, `result` ends up being `None`, and cannot be iterated over in the call to `self.assertIn`.

Comment: You're not passing a method here, and you don't want to.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. How can I check if "code" is inside JSON object returned in client.createDepositAddress({"currencySymbol":"BTC"})

Comment: You should describe us the structure of the JSON object returned by `client.createDepositAddress({"currencySymbol":"BTC"})` otherwise is difficult to answer.

Comment: Thank you, just edited my question

Comment: `client.createDepositAddress` does not appear to *be* returning either a JSON object or a `dict`; `result` appears to be the value `None`.